# Can't log in to facebook using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to log in to facebook using requests module. Although it seems I've prepared payload in the right way but when I send it with post requests, I don't get desired content in the response. I get 200 status code, though. To let you know, If I get response accordingly, I should find my fullname within it.

I initially tried like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com{}'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://www.facebook.com/',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    form_url = soup.select_one("form[data-testid='royal_login_form']")['action']
    post_url = base_url.format(form_url)
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['email'] = 'YOUR_EMAIL'
    payload['encpass'] = f'#PWD_BROWSER:0:{time}:YOUR_PASSWORD'
    payload.pop('pass')
    res = s.post(post_url,data=payload,headers=headers)
    print(res.url)
    print(res.text)
```

This is another way I tried which didn't work out either:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

login_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=101'
time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://www.facebook.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=101'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['email'] = 'YOUR_EMAIL'
    payload['encpass'] = f'#PWD_BROWSER:0:{time}:YOUR_PASSWORD'
    payload['had_password_prefilled'] = 'true'
    payload['had_cp_prefilled'] = 'true'
    payload['prefill_source'] = 'browser_dropdown'
    payload['prefill_type'] = 'contact_point'
    payload['first_prefill_source'] = 'last_login'
    payload['first_prefill_type'] = 'contact_point'
    payload['prefill_contact_point'] = 'YOUR_EMAIL'
    payload.pop('pass')
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
```

> How can I log in to facebook using requests?

Comment: What is the response you are getting? I tried intercepting a login request, and it looked something like this:
`jazoest=****
lsd=***********
email=MY_EMAIL
login_source=comet_headerless_login
next=
encpass=#PWD_BROWSER:ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD`. Is your password encrypted using the same algorithm they use, and do you know whether those other parameters are necessary?

Comment: It appears that facebook requires the `lsd` parameter for the login request to work; otherwise, although the response looks okay, the browser would then redirect to a "Your Request Couldn't be Processed" screen.

Comment: Those parameters are generated randomly when the webpage loads, and are stored within an input tag. So you would likely need to pull a version of the webpage to get those values before you can make the request. This page seems to address a similar problem: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/e9ade12a-b98a-4099-9899-03c1332f80c0/y

Comment: The value of `lsd` is already there in payload. You can see all the parameters used in payload when you print `payload`. As for the encryption of password is concerned, when you use `0` in this portion `:0:`, you can use your password as it is. However, when it is `:5:`, you have to use encrypted password.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a case of [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

I recommend trying [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in accessing Facebook programmatically.

More examples using Selenium in logging in.

https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/python-automate-facebook-login

https://www.guru99.com/facebook-login-using-python.html

Answer (score -1):

If logging in is all that you require, then using selenium, you could do it as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(URL)
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email.send_keys('YourEmail')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password.send_keys('YourPassword')
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I would recommend that you use the browser that you frequently use to login for this process.